# Function to preload images?

Tags: javascript, preload

I'm successfully pre-loading an image on my website with this JavaScript:

```
loveHover = new Image();
loveHover.src = "http://mypage.com/images/love-hover.png";
```

Is there an easy an good way to pack this thing into a function? Something like:

```
function preloadImage(image) {
    var image = new Image();
    var path = "http://mypage.com/images/";
    image.src = path + image;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
["love-hover.jpg", "like-hover.jpg", "hate-hover.jpg"].forEach(function(img)
{
    new Image().src = "http://mypage.com/" + img;
});
```

To get this to work in IE versions earlier than 9, see the [Array.forEach Compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach#Compatibility) for instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Well the unique part of the function would be the src (link to image). So make that the argument.

```
function preloadImage(src) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
}
```

Then if you have multiple urls store them in an array:

```
var imageSrcs = [
    "http://mypage.com/images/love-hover.png#",
    "http://mypage.com/images/love-hover2.png",
    "http://mypage.com/images/love-hover3.png"
];
```

And preload the images with a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imageSrcs.lengthl i++)
    preloadImage(imageSrcs[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried not using javascript at all?

http://perishablepress.com/press/2008/06/14/a-way-to-preload-images-without-javascript-that-is-so-much-better/